# Is there a better way to write closely related nested if conditions in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is an example:

```
if is_important
  if votes < 500
    votes = 3000
  else
    votes = votes * 10
  end
else
  if votes < 500
    votes = 8000
  else
    votes = votes * 5
  end
end
```

I'm trying to find the best way to write such nested `if`/`else` conditions in a more cleaner way in Ruby.

Comment: Consider moving this to [codereview.se].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me "cleaner way" is having a simple interface, which does not force me to dive into implementation details (but when I have to, it should be easy to read):

```
def count(votes)
  is_important ? count_important(votes) : count_not_important(votes)
end

private

def count_important(votes)
  votes < 500 ? 3000 : votes * 10
end

def count_not_important(votes)
  votes < 500 ? 8000 : votes * 5
end
```

P.S. With this simple task an `if/else` statement should be enough though.

Answer (score 2):

```
votes = 
  if is_important
    (votes < 500) ? 3000 : votes * 10
  else
    (votes < 500) ? 8000 : votes * 5
  end
```

In  ruby if-else, case statements return the value after evaluating the expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can always just flatten your nesting. Also, don't forget to check that votes actually is there because you have a few returns that assume its presence.

```
votes = 0 unless votes
votes = if is_important && votes < 500 
    3000
elsif is_important 
    votes * 10
elsif votes < 500
    8000
else
    votes * 5
end
```

also you could use then with if and get

```
votes = 0 unless votes
votes = if is_important && votes < 500 then 3000
elsif is_important then votes * 10
elsif votes < 500 then 8000
else votes * 5
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. Here is a DRY and compact, but perhaps too odd one:

```
votes = 
  case [is_important, votes < 500]
    when [true, true]   then 3000
    when [true, false]  then votes * 10
    when [false, true]  then 5000
    when [false, false] then votes * 5
    end
```